# Unable to find my files, but they take up space

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I've created a new Ubuntu installation and wanted to copy my old files over, but I had complications so I booted into a LiveUSB and did the copying part there, and everything seemed to go fine (files copied, etc.). However, when I boot into the new Ubuntu installations I can't find the files; they are not in the location where I copied them, however the space seems to be allocated for them.

```
df -h shows (this is a fresh install so those 100 GB must be my files)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  451G  113G  315G  27% /

du -sh /home/username/ shows only 58 MB
58M    /home/username/
```

However, when I open the Disk Usage analyzer I get these: [overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YG4h.png),
[overview of /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2811.png) which seems to indicated my files are there somewhere.

I've tried `find` and `locate`, but they didn't find my files. Also running `du -sh /*` shows that no folder is bigger than 3 GB.

Comment: `find -name [Files]` or `whereis [Files]`

Comment: did you accidentally hide them? also check lost&found

Comment: Please summarize your current disk layout (did you create a separate home partition / LV, or is everything in the root LV?) and how you copied the files when booted into the LivsUSB - is it possible you copied the files but then mounted /home over them?

Comment: Add the output of: `sudo du -hxd1 /; df -i; df -h; sudo lsof | grep deleted` to your post, please.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have a strong suspicion you have another partition mounted on `/home`. When you booted to a live USB, you didn't mount that partition, so files copied to your home directory were copied to your home directory on the partition mounted on `/`. When Ubuntu boots and mounts something on `/home`, the old contents are effectively inaccessible until you unmount `/home`.

You can bind mount `/` elsewhere to access the directory masked by other mounts:

```
mkdir foo
sudo mount --bind / foo
du -sh foo/home
```

Answer (score 4):

If you open a terminal and `cd /` then this command

`sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20`

will show you the 20 largest directories (including subdirs) in your file system - it does take a while to run the first time.  You can then change to what looks like a larger than expected directory, and run the command again, looking for again bigger then expected directories, and hopefully you will eventually find your files.

```
chick@dad:/$ sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20
[sudo] password for chick: 
du: cannot access './proc/30738/task/30738/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/30738/task/30738/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/30738/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/30738/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
655023M .
645220M ./home
5481M   ./usr
2049M   ./swapfile
860M    ./lib
668M    ./var
491M    ./opt
201M    ./boot
17M ./sbin
16M ./etc
15M ./bin
11M ./run
1M  ./tmp
1M  ./srv
1M  ./snap
1M  ./root
1M  ./mnt
1M  ./media
1M  ./lost+found
1M  ./lib64
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 0. Read `man locate`.
Step 1. Ensure the `locate` database is up-to-date:

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/locate
```

This will take several minutes - have patience.

Step 2. Use `locate` to find one of your files that has a unique-to-you name. E.g.:

```
locate GeorgeRomero_Birth_Certificate
```

(if your name is "George Romero". Mine isn't, YMMV.)

Step 3. Read `man mv` and consider using `mv` to move a whole directory structure to where you want it. E.g., if the Step 2 locate showed:

```
/some/where/Documents/GeorgeRomero_Birth_Certificate
```

you could do something like `mv --target-directory=$HOME /some/where/Documents`.

Comment: Locate didn't return anything (I've already tried to find the files using `find`)

Answer (score 3):

More simply, you could

```
sudo find / -type f -name GeorgeRomero_Birth_Certificate -print
```

Comment: Complete aside: why George Romero's birth certificate?